# VSCode's memory view doesn't work through a debug restart

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing an debugger for VSCode for an emulated system, because of this I need to be able to view the emulated system's memory a lot.

The memory feature in VSCode works, has to be opened each time a debugging session is started. (With the original closed, which is a pain as there is no indication it is 'disconnected'.)

Is there a way to get persuade VSCode to 'reattach' a memory window each time the debugger starts?